# Python: Rename multiple files in folder with name that come from a list

Tags: python

I want to build a small app that renameS files that are in a folder with some names that are in a txt file like so:

in **C:\python\Folder** i have files: **1436790.pdf 1436791.pdf 1436792.pdf**

in **file.txt** I have 3 lines:

1. x
2. y
3. z

Renaming should be:

1. 1436790.pdf -> x.pdf
2. 1436791.pdf -> y.pdf
3. 1436792.pdf -> z.pdf

I can't figure out how `os.rename()` is working. I'm getting this error

```
**"OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect:"**
```

I tried to make this app in a similar way with Total Commander multi rename tool (load names from file).

Comment: How can we help without a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

```
basefolder=r'C:\python\Folder'
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fh:
    read_lines = fh.readlines()
files=os.listdir(basefolder)
for file in r(files):
    fn,fext=os.path.splitext(files[file])
    os.rename(files[file], read_lines[file]+fext )
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is due to the pytest/Python bug issue. Refer
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5724

For now try downgrading to Python 3.7.3 until someone finds a fix.